# Monaco Editor: Configure libs by editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm building a page that contains multiple monaco editors. I currently control the libraries I want to use by using:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(`

        interface Product {
          foo: String;
        }

        declare const product: Product;

`, 'global.d.ts')
```

By using this, all the editors are forced to have exactly the same libraries available.

**Is it possible to control that behavior by editor instance and not globally?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short: no.

The problem is that the [`IStandaloneCodeEditor`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html) you create by calling [`monaco.editor.create ()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#create) has no idea of any of the [`monaco.languages`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html) that are currently available and registered.

The parsing is done by [`monaco.worker`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.worker.html)s, which get - for Java- and TypeScript - configured through [`monaco.languages.typescript`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.typescript.html) and are static and not instance-specific, so that one worker serves many instances.

I believe this design decision was made in favour of efficiency and performance - having may `WebWorker`s for many instances with (probably) many different libraries is not very efficient.

Also note that this is not the only thing that is not configurable instance-wise: everything which is configurable via any `monaco.languages` language definition is global.

I do not know how this is exactly implemented, but if you are willing to understand what is happening, the [Type- and JavaScript implementation is on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-typescript) (as well as [Monaco's base](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor)).

Though it would be (probably) somewhat performance-heavy, this is something which may be suitable to be discussed in an [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues). In the end, if this is declined, you might as well just have got an impression on the implementation of Monaco by the contributors.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. You're getting the bounty I guess even if I'm disappointed by the truth you just said. As a consolation for me, if you have any recommendation of a library I should use to give my application a cool javascript editor that can provide a different auto-completion for multiple editors on a single page, I would be more than happy with that... Have a nice day anyways :) I'm so sad that this beautiful monaco library is not more accessible for beginners like me... I guess that its complexity is justified by its multiple functionalities!

Comment: You're welcome and as for the recommendation, I stumbled across Monaco also searching for an editor supporting auto-completion, and so far it's the very best I've found. And yes, it's very complex (just take a look at what it takes to add a new, custom language), but brings - as you said - many advantages. However, it's open source, so you are welcomed to implement your own solution to this problem, but I think the little outcome does not justify this huge effort. (But I honestly do not think that such a con really lowers your app's usability, there are apps with more serious cons out there..)